# Send Email using froala editor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, froala

I'm using froala editor to design my email body, and the email contain images, what I'm doing is save that image to specific server and get image from that server.

But the problem is if my server will be close or stop working the images will not shown. What can I to over come this issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you save and retrieve your image to the server, they reside on server side.

If your server is not down (not working) you won't be able to save / retrieve your images from it.